# Advice on falling function

Tags: algorithm, math

this one is maybe pretty stupid.. Or I am just exhausted or something, but I just cant seem to solve it..

Problem : two variables X and Y, value of Y is dependent on value of X. X can have values ranging from some value to some value (lets say from 0 to 250) and y can have different values (lets say from 0.1 to 1.0 or something..) - but it is inverse relatonship (what I mean is: if value of X is e.g. 250, then value of Y would be 0.1 and when X decreases up to 0, value of Y raises up to 1.0..

So how should I do it? lets say I have function:
-- double computeValue (double X) { /*computation*/  return Y; }

Also, is there some easy way to somehow make the scaling of the function not so linear? - For example when X raises, Y decreases slower at first but then more rapidly in the end.. (rly dont know how to say it but I hope you guys got it)

Thanks in advance for this stupid question :/

Edit - changed the title.

Edit - Thanks guys, I appreciate your quick responses. Have a nice day everyone.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an inverse relation. It is just a falling function. Maybe, you look for something like:

f(x) = Sqrt(1-x/250) * 0.9 + 0.1

[image: Plot of function]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function Y=C^(-X). where C>1, depending on the 'fall' you like.

Answer (score 1):

X' = (X - X_min) / (X_max - X_min)

**now** 0 <= X' <= 1

**To make it reverse let**

X'' = 1 - X'

**To get linear scaling:**

Y = X'' * (Y_max - Y_min) + Y_min

**To get other scaling:**

Y = scalling_function(X'') * (Y_max - Y_min) + Y_min

**And scalling_function can be:**

scalling_function(a) = a*a

scalling_function(a) = sqrt(a)